# Find NSDate for the next closest specific day of week for any date

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, date-arithmetic

Let's suppose that today is Wednesday. I can break an `NSDate` down into `NSDateComponents`, but I need to find the `NSDate` with the next *upcoming* Monday. If today is Monday, then the next *upcoming* Monday is today. What's the right way to achieve this?

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates , and it has a `mt_startOfNextWeek;` method.

Comment: I need a solution without any third part libraries

Comment: Do you mean the next *upcoming* Monday, or just the *closest* (which could be in the past or in the future) ?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `nextDateAfterDate:` method on `NSCalendar` object to achieve this,

```
let now = Date() // today

var matchingComponents = DateComponents()
matchingComponents.weekday = 2 // Monday

let comingMonday =  Calendar.current.nextDate(after: now,
                                              matching: matchingComponents,
                                              matchingPolicy:.nextTime)
```

Here, is a simple method to find next monday. If today is Monday the following function returns today or else the closest next Monday. Note that it uses **en_POSIX_US** such that the days can be matched. When the locale is **en_POSIX_US**, weekdays symbols become,

```
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

And, here is how this days could be used,

```
func findNext(_ day: String, afterDate date: Date) -> Date? {

    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let weekDaySymbols = calendar.weekdaySymbols
    let indexOfDay = weekDaySymbols.index(of: day)

    assert(indexOfDay != nil, "day passed should be one of \(weekDaySymbols), invalid day: \(day)")

    let weekDay = indexOfDay! + 1

    let components = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)

    if components == weekDay {
        return date
    }

    var matchingComponents = DateComponents()
    matchingComponents.weekday = weekDay // Monday

    let nextDay = calendar.nextDate(after: date,
                                    matching: matchingComponents,
                                    matchingPolicy:.nextTime)
    return nextDay!
}


let nextMonday = findNext("Monday", afterDate: Date())
let mondayAfterThat = findNext("Monday", afterDate: nextMonday!)

let thursday = findNext("Thursday", afterDate: mondayAfterThat!)
```

Comment: this is the best solution I think:)

Comment: It's amazing that `NSCalendar`'s iOS 8 methods are still undocumented on the reference library.

Comment: Yes, they seem to have added many new apis to NSCalendar and siblings. It would be really good to have them documented.

Comment: "Monday" will not work for other languages, `Monday` in polish is `Poniedziałek` for instance. I think that searching by name is not the best solution since calendars in devices are automatically localised.

Comment: That is the reason that locale is used for the calendar with en_US_POSIX, see that it uses the system calendar but sets locale to en_US_POSIX, just to extract english name.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

for target iOS >= 8 use GeneratorOfOne's solution

else you can use this

```
let now = NSDate()
var lastMonday:NSDate?
var nextMonday:NSDate?
var start:NSDate?        

var interval:NSTimeInterval = 0   // holds the length of a week. can differ for Daylight Saving Time
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)! // have a own calendar object for this calculation to guarantee that the next line does not influence other calculations 
cal.firstWeekday = 2              // make sure first day of week is Monday. 


cal.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfMonth, startDate: &lastMonday, interval:&interval, forDate: now)      // monday of current week
nextMonday = lastMonday?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)  // add a weeks length to the last weeks's monday
println(nextMonday)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can get the week day by using `NSDateComponents` and calculate the interval days, then use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` from `NSDate` like so:

```
let now = NSDate()
let calendar: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: now)
let weekday = calendar.weekday  // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday

// You get input the weekday here and calculate the interval

// exmaple for moving to the next day
let expectedDate = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(1 * 24 * 60 * 60)

// exmaple for moving to yesterday
let yesterday = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: **Don't** use 24*60*60 seconds as the duration of a day (think of daylight saving time transitions).

Comment: @MartinR sorry. I don't follow. Can you explain this again?

Comment: days can be 23, 24, 25 hours long, due to Daylight Saving Times